# Template specialization as a function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-studio-2015

Consider the following code:

```
typedef void(__cdecl *logging_fnc)(int, const char*, ...);

template<logging_fnc LogFnc>
class Logger {
public:
  void foo()
  {
    LogFnc(1, "Foo");
  }

};

template<class Target, Target& instance>
void MakeLogAtTarget(int lvl, const char* msg...)
{
   instance.log("specific foo", lvl, msg);
}
```

The `Logger` somewhere simply calls the non-type template `LogFnc` from some method.

Now I also have a singleton class `MyTarget`.

```
class MyTarget {
public:
  void log(const char* targetSpecific, int lvl, const char* msg)
  {
    printf("%s %s", targetSpecific, msg);
  }

  static MyTarget& GetInstance()
  {
    static MyTarget myInstance;
    return myInstance;
  }

private:
  MyTarget() = default;
};
```

Why exactly the following doesn't work?

```
using TargetLogger = Logger<MakeLogAtTarget<MyTarget, MyTarget::GetInstance()>>;
```

I keep getting: `cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(int,const char *,...)' to 'logging_fnc'`

Is it simply because the compiler cannot get the proper address of the specialization of `MakeLogAtTarget` it generates?

Generally speaking: is it possible to feed the non-template argument a pointer to a function which in turn invokes a method from some class instance?

**UPDATE**: Also tried

```
static const MyTarget targetInstance = MyTarget::GetInstance();
using TargetLogger = Logger<MakeLogAtTarget<MyTarget, targetInstance)>>;
```

Still the same error.

**UPDATE**

```
static const MyTarget targetInstance = MyTarget::GetInstance();
static const logging_fnc targetFnc = MakeLogAtTarget<MyTarget, targetInstance>;
using TargetLogger = Logger<targetFnc>;
```

outputs the same error at the line where `targetFnc` is declared, moreover an additional error appears at the last line:
`'targetFnc': an expression involving objects with internal linkage cannot be used as a non-type argument`

Comment: Have you tried `typedef void(__cdecl *logging_fnc)(int,const char*,...);`?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. Your current code is not valid C++

Comment: A quick experiment shows that Clang does not like your template argument for `instance`. GCC produces a less descriptive error message .

Comment: Do fewer things per line.  `constexpr logging_fnc bob = MakeLogAtTarget<MyTarget, targetInstance)>;`, then `Logger<bob>`.  Test with fewer restrictions: `logginc_fnc bob = MakeLogAtTarget<MyTarget, targetInstance)>;`.  This is part of making your problem **minimal**.  [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2578bb704827d02) of a clearly more minimal solution.

Comment: Just tried your example, if you put `--std=c++11` in `g++` you get the variant of the error I'm getting in VS2015.

Comment: @NumberFour [C++11 in clang and gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f1c47fba1f19ef0).  Note that non-type template arguments coming from `constexpr` expressions where more permitted after C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. It seems that you have a singleton instance that you want to feed to a logger? I'm missing the bigger picture.

```
template<class Target, Target& instance>
```

Here it seems you want to use an instance of an object as a template parameter. However, afaik templates are a compile-time construct, while the instance is generated at run-time. This construction would be impossible in that case. But I'm no expert.

edit: hmm, a -1 feedback modifier again. The guys/gal doing that should comment why.

edit 2:
So now I understand your problem better. But then again the question: is it required to have `MakeLogAtTarget` fully template-able?

What you can do is use function pointers as template arguments. E.g.:

```
template<class Target, Target& (*Getter)()>
void MakeLogAtTarget(int lvl, const char* msg...)
{
    Getter().log("specific foo", lvl, msg);
}
```

Thus you can call it using:

```
using TargetLogger = Logger < MakeLogAtTarget < MyTarget, MyTarget::GetInstance >> ;
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The `Logger` class is a facade for different types of loggers, some are simple ones (i.e. `void Log(int level,char* Message)`), some are more complex singleton classes, which `MakeLogAtTarget` will translate to.

Comment: No, my question is not what a logger is, but what you are trying to accomplish. For instance: why not implement a log function in MyTarget?
I still think you should add some simple example code to clarify your problems: something we can compile, to get your errors, and can fix to solve them.

Comment: The purpose of  the `Logger` class is to unify APIs of different loggers, there's nothing more behind it really. The other singletons like `MyTarget` represent the other loggers I'm wrapping and they are not something I can change actually. The code from the question actually compiles and illustrates the compiler problem I'm getting.

Comment: well, it compiles if I implement my own main() function.
But I changed my answer to include a code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your edits - the problem is that `MyTarget::log` is never static in my case nor the `GetInstance()` method is same across singletons.

Comment: So you have a singleton, that is not a single instance?? That defies the definition of singleton...
I'm really missing the bigger picture here... you're description is too vague: what is the application, why is log not static, etc, etc. Without proper information, it is very difficult to give proper feedback.

Comment: I never said they are not singletons. What I'm saying they do not always have `GetInstance` method - sometimes it is just `get`, sometimes `GetLogger()`...etc. `MakeLogAtTarget` simple needs to know the actual instance that must've been obtained beforehand by its specific getter and still it has to adhere to `logging_fnc` prototype.

Comment: As I wrote: templates are compiler-time constructs, so you cannot pass a run-time instance as a parameter. I've edited my answer again: now it shows a way to pass the instance-getter function as a template argument.

Comment: I know, but the whole thing lies in C++11 having too strict requirements on `constexpr` as noted in other posts. Unfortunately, I cant build with newer standard, so I have to make a workaround. I actually like the idea of passing the getter as a template arg instead of the actual instance. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Compilation of templates itself does not generate anything in the binary. Only when they are called happens the instantiation. Only then will the compiler check and generate binaries for the given arguments. It will not be generated in run-time. That is why templates are faster than polymorphism.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is you're failing to meet the requirements for the template non-type argument of type `Target&`. From [temp.arg.nontype]:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* shall be a converted constant expression (5.20) of the type of the *template-parameter*.

Where a converted constant expression prohibits, from [expr.const]:

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions: [...] an invocation of a function other than a `constexpr` constructor for a literal class, a `constexpr` function, or an implicit invocation of a trivial destructor (12.4)

You'll need some specific `MyTarget` object to refer to (or, in a post-[N4198](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html) world, a `constexpr` function that returns such a thing or something similar). Like:

```
struct MyTarget { ... };
static MyTarget x;

using TargetLogger = Logger<MakeLogAtTarget<MyTarget,x>>;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I tried something similar you suggest (see edits), but I still keep getting the same error in VS2015. Didn't try GCC though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can probably be reduced to a simple

```
template <typename T, T& t> void bar() {}

struct Z
{
  static constexpr Z& get();
};

static Z z;

constexpr Z& Z::get() { return z; }

int main()
{
    bar<Z, Z::get()>();
}
```

In C++11 and C++14 modes GCC responds with

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:14:22: error: no matching function for call to 'bar()'
     bar<Z, Z::get()>();
                      ^
main.cpp:1:34: note: candidate: template<class T, T& t> void bar()
 template <typename T, T& t> void bar() {}
                                  ^~~
main.cpp:1:34: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:14:22: error: 'Z::get()' is not a valid template argument for type 'Z&' because it is not an object with linkage
     bar<Z, Z::get()>();
                      ^
```

It does not like your attempt to use a function return as an argument for a reference-typed template parameter.

Once the code becomes more complicated (like yours) the descriptive error messages disappear, replaced with the message you quoted or a very similar one.

Yet, it compiles fine in `-std=c++17` mode.

Comment: That's a gcc bug if it doesn't compile. Looks like it's been fixed though.

Comment: @Barry: godbolt does not show it as fixed in GCC 7. The behavior still depends in `-std=` setting as described above.

Comment: [N4198](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html) loosened the requirements, I thought that was for C++14 but maybe not.